# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (7, 9, 384, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the tensorflow as the backend. I'm using the 3D convolution layer in keras. My final x training data is in shape (7,9,384,1), channel equals to 1, y training data is in shape (7,1,384,1). I keep getting this error when it runs model.fit().

I checked out most of the related problems posted online, but they all kind of focus on whether it's theaon or tensorflow as the backend. Some of them suggests expand dimensions, but still doesn't work and some other problems showed up.

According to the keras documents, 3D convolution should have a 5D input shape, and I am lacking the first dimension samples. I only have this one 3D data input (in shape 7,9,384), and I tried adding a 1 at the beginning of the input_shape parameter in the first layer, and it will cause another problem saying that I exceeded one dimension in the input shape.

Can anyone please take a look and tell me what's wrong? Thank you so much!

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

# Read the array from disk
data = np.loadtxt('D:/8_CNN_pycharm/data.txt', delimiter=',')
x = data[:,1:10]
y = data[:,0]

rownum = np.size(x,0)
# boundIndex = 384
boundIndex = int(rownum/7/3*2)  
x_train = x[0:7*boundIndex,:]
y_train = y[0:7*boundIndex]
x_test = x[7*boundIndex:,:]
y_test = y[7*boundIndex:]
print(rownum)
print(x_train.shape[0])
print(x_test.shape)

# Going to 3D array using desired shape of the array
new_x_train = x_train.reshape(7,9,boundIndex,1)
# new_x_train = new_x_train.reshape(new_x_train.shape[0],7,9,boundIndex,1)
# new_x_train = np.expand_dims(new_x_train,axis=0)

new_y_train = y_train.reshape(7,1,boundIndex,1)
# new_y_train = np.expand_dims(new_y_train,axis=0)
print(new_x_train.shape[:])
# x_input = Input(shape=(7,9,boundIndex, 1))

new_x_test = x_test.reshape((7,9,int(rownum/7-boundIndex)))
new_y_test = y_test.reshape((7,1,int(rownum/7-boundIndex)))

model = Sequential()
# model.add(Conv2D(64, (4,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(7,9,boundIndex)))
model.add(Conv3D(64, (4,3,2), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(7,9,boundIndex,1)))
model.add(Conv3D(32, (4,3,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2), padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv3D(16, (2,2,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling3D())
model.add(Dense(7, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(new_x_train, new_y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
score = model.evaluate(new_x_test, new_y_test, batch_size=16)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "E:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "E:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "E:/CNN/myCNN/myFirstCNN.py", line 67, in <module>
    model.fit(new_x_train, new_y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)   File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 963, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)   File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)   File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1476, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')   File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (7, 9, 384, 1)
```

Comment: why not use a 2D conv layer?

Comment: The way you have stated your problem, it seems like Keras is expecting a 5D tensor, and you're feeding it a 4D tensor. Based on your description of the problem, the only thing I can think of is using 'reshape' in NumPy to reshape the input to a 5D tensor. Can you try this? Also, could you please share your data?

Comment: @troymyname00, yes, you are right, I did try that and it worked, the correct form should be  (1,7,9,boundIndex,1), just as the answer goes! Thank you!

Comment: What's important is to figure out the difference between input shape and input_shape, which is the concept of tensor.

Comment: @skmth Thank you for your concern! Because I want to explore both spatial and temporal effects in the sample. In that case, I think 3D is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input_shape that a keras layer expects is per sample. So the shape of x should be one dimension bigger than input_shape. I don't know what the 7 means in your data but if this is the number of samples than you should not include it in input_shape, so input_shape becomes:

(9,boundIndex,1).

If you only train on 1 sample (for some reason) you could reshape x to:

(1,7,9,boundIndex,1)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, you are right, I take (7,9,boundIndex,1) as a whole data sample, so the dimension for sample should be 1 in my case. (1,7,9,boundIndex,1) is correct! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to reply so late, I was studying it all this time, and I figured it out myself, but I would like to thank you again!